# About jquery append behavior

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have the following code:

```
$.getJSON('/api/video/',
      function (resp) {
          $("body").append("<ul/>");

          $.each(resp, function (key, value) {
              $("ul").append("<li/>").append(
                  $("<a/>", {
                      href: value.url,
                      html: value.title
                  }));
          });
      });
```

It produces:

```
...
<ul>
    <li></li>
    <a href="http://vimeo.com/1234567">How to Connect a Mobile Broadband Antenna to Data Card</a>
    <li></li>
    <a href="http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=q4Oknc8onG8">40000mW Laser vs. Line of Balloons!!</a>
</ul>
...
```

As you can see the `<a/>` are not inside `<li/>` and my question is why (is there a good reason for the behavior or does it just work that way)? In my world `$("ul").append("<li/>").append($("<a/>", ...))` adds the `<a/>` inside a `<li/>`. I see it as `$("ul").append("<li/>")` creates an `<li/>` inside the unorderd list and that the next append operates on the `<li/>` item and thus should add the link inside of it. However that is not the case and I wonder if there is a reason for that?

I am very grateful that you have taken time for my question!

Comment: $(this).prepend('content'); is used for append at the begging...

Comment: `$("ul").append("<li/>")` returns the ul.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `.append()` function doesn't update the element(s) referenced by the jQuery object, so when you call the second `.append()` it's still being called against the `<ul>` element.

You could restructure it like so:

```
$('<li/>').append('<a/>', {
    href: value.url,
    title: value.title
}).appendTo('ul');
```

Comment: Greate fast and clear answer! It even included a clean easy example! Thanks very much!

Answer (score 1):

`$.append()` returns the item that was appended to, not the item being appended.

Comment: Thanks for taking time to aswer my question. It was a very good explanation.